# Ajax call not passing php variables

Tags: php, ajax

I have php variables $subscriber_phone and $agent_phone on a page where i make an ajax call to a call.php page after clicking a button with ID **#call**. I have the following ajax code.

The alert for customernumber gives undefined. The php variable is not getting passed through.

**Ajax:**

```
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
var customernumber;
var agentnumber;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#call").click(function(){
        customernumber: "<?php echo $subscriber_phone;?>";
        agentnumber: "<?php echo $agent_phone;?>";
        alert(customernumber);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Call_Agent/call/call.php",
            cache: false,
            dataType : "text",
            data: {customernumber : customernumber,agentnumber : agentnumber},
            success: function(data) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong??? Requesting help!!

Comment: Look at the source in the browser, you'll be able to see how the page is being parsed, since PHP processes before the page is sent to the browser. If the data doesn't show there, then you'll need to investigate why it doesn't.

Comment: php is displaying the phone number correctly in the page. I echoed it.

Comment: alert displaying "undefined"

Comment: You're not assigning the value to `customernumber` correct. I'm surprised it's not giving other errors, since you're using object syntax in a non-object  context. You need to assign the value with `=` instead.

Comment: @aynber My goodness...Wonder what i was doing..Thank you so much.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is at

```
customernumber: "<?php echo $subscriber_phone;?>";
```

This is object syntax in a non-object context. Use the equal sign instead.

```
$("#call").click(function(){
customernumber = "<?php echo $subscriber_phone;?>";
agentnumber = "<?php echo $agent_phone;?>";
alert(customernumber);
```

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. Wonder what i was doing..I made few changes and in the process missed it. Thank you so much.